# Using grunt and phantomjs with a jetty server

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, jetty, gruntjs

I'm trying to run the grunt-yslow test on a jetty server. I have a `server_start` and a `server_stop` task in between need to run the yslow task.

A first approach of using `child_process.spawn()` within `server_start` and then running the whole thing using

```
grunt.task.run('server_start', 'yslow_test', 'server_stop');
```

results in the terminal hanging at

```
Running "server_start" task
Starting java server....
Running "yslow_test:your_target" (yslow_test) task
Command: phantomjs /.../node_modules/grunt-yslow-test/tasks/lib/yslow.js -i grade -f junit http://localhost:8080/cms/s/0/1251659c-efb2-11e2-ad61-002128161462.html
```

***edit** it turned out this was also partly to do with installing phantomjs via npm rather than as a standalone binary, but after installing the binary correctly the htlm page still failed to load*

Using a more sophisticated approach of listening for server data events and only running ySlow after the last start up output of the server has been emitted results in some strange behaviour (see the comments below). (I've removed all the try/catch blocks for brevity, but no errors are ever thrown)

```
var server;

grunt.registerTask('runYslow', 'Initialise a test server to run tests against', function() {
    //If I don't include yslow_test here then no normal server startup output is generated. 
    //If I do include yslow_test then the startup output is emitted and then yslow behaviour is bizarrely influenced by which events I listen to on the spawned server process!
    grunt.task.run(['server_start', 'yslow_test']);

});

grunt.registerTask('server_start', 'Start the web server', function () {

    var javaParams = ['-jar', 'target/the.jar', 'server', 'config-local.yml'],
        count = 0;

        server = grunt.util.spawn({
            cmd: 'java',
            args: javaParams
        });

        server.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');

        // If I include this listener somewhere between 13 and 17 events are fired
        // but the contents of read() are always null
        server.stdout.on('readable', function() {  
            console.log(count++, server.stdout.read());
        });

        // If I include this listener 7 events are fired ONLY IF I run yslow_test in the 
        // runYslow task. otherwise absolutely nothing is output. When the events are
        // fired the content of data is the normal startup messages of the jetty server
        server.stdout.on('data', function(chunk) {
            console.log(chunk);
            if (chunk.indexOf('Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8085') > -1) {
                // never run unless yslow_test is already called within runYslow
                grunt.task.run(['yslow_test']);
            }

        });
});
```

I suppose my question is a particular case of the broader one of how to have grunt start and stop non-nodejs servers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my eventual solution

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    "use strict";

    grunt.registerTask('runYslow', 'Initialise a test server to run tests against', function() {
        try {
            //queue these tasks to happen one after the other
            grunt.task.run('server_start', 'yslow_test', 'server_stop');
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('runYslow: err is', err);
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('server_start', 'Start the web server', function () {
        //this needs to not be hard coded - i.e. the version number needs to be got dynamically from somewhere
        var javaParams = ['-jar', 'target/my.jar', 'server', 'config-local.yml'],
            done = this.async(),
            server;
        try {
            grunt.log.write('Starting java server....');

            server = process.env.JETTY_SERVER || grunt.util.spawn({
                cmd: 'java',
                args: javaParams
            });

            server.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');

            server.stdout.on('data', function(chunk) {
                if (chunk.indexOf('the last thing your server logs to confirm startup was successful') > -1) {
                    done();
                }
            });

            process.env.JETTY_SERVER = server;

        } catch (err) {
            console.log('server_start: err is', err);
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('server_stop', 'Stop the web server', function () {
        try {
            grunt.log.write('Killing java server....');
            process.kill(process.env.JETTY_SERVER.pid, 'SIGINT');
            delete process.env.JETTY_SERVER;
            grunt.log.write('Killed java server.');
        } catch (err) {
            grunt.log.write('Error whilst killing java server');
        }
    });
};
```